# Query in a while loop, how can I improve the speed of this? Two DB Types

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

*edit*
Thought i need to add more info. This first query is MySQL, the latter two are PGSQL, and its located on a seperate server. When i disable the second query in the second part of this, its still just as slow.

```
SELECT n.id, n.number, n.assigned, n.btn, n.status as stat, s.status 
FROM numbers n 
LEFT JOIN status s on n.status=s.id 
where number like '239333%'
LIMIT $start, $limit
```

I have the following query, this pulls a range of numbers from a DB, this is a pretty quick query, as I have it limited to 50 or 100.

This lists the output in a while loop in PHP..

Within this while loop, there is a second connection to a seperate server (postgres) to do additional checks on this number which is done through a function, so in the loop i have for example $mq = addition_checks($number);

```
$query = "SELECT count(baseinformation_directorynumber) as count FROM \"public\".\"meta_subscriber\" WHERE baseinformation_directorynumber = $number";
$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
$row = pg_fetch_assoc($result);
$did = "0";
if ($row['count'] == '0') {
    $query2 = "SELECT count(lastdirectorynumber) as count FROM \"public\".\"meta_pbx_directinwardcalling\" where firstdirectorynumber <= $number and $number <= lastdirectorynumber";
    $result2 = pg_query($query2) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
    $row2 = pg_fetch_assoc($result2);
    if ($row2['count'] == '1') { 
        $did = $row2['count'];
        $row['count'] = "0";
    }

}

pg_free_result($result);

// Closing connection

$line = $row['count'];
$match = array('line' => $line, 'did' =>  $did);
return $match;
```

After this I do a couple more checks to display the information as needed.

The problem is that when I added the additional_checks query, it takes about 30 seconds to load 50 items. Im asking (due to lack of knowledge) how I can increase the speed of this to be a little more acceptable.

If it helps, here it my main while look

```
while ($q->getrow()) {
$number = $q->field('number'); $assigned = $q->field('assigned'); $btn = $q->field('btn'); $id = $q->field('id'); $status = $q->field('status'); $stat = $q->field('stat');
$nc++; //Start Counter
$now = time(); 
$diff = $now - $time; 
if ($alternate == "1") {
    $color = "#EFEFEF";
    $alternate = "2";
} else {
    $color = "#DFDFDF";
    $alternate = "1";
}
$match = meta_query($q->field('number'));
if ($match['line'] == '1' and $match['did'] == '0') { 
    $numcolor = "green";
    $did = "";
} elseif ($match['did'] == '1' AND $match['line'] == '0') { 
    $did = "[DID]"; 
    $numcolor = "green";
} else {
    $did = "";
    if ((!$assigned) AND (!$btn) AND ($stat == '1' OR $stat == '4')) {
        $numcolor = "";
    } else {
        $numcolor = "red";
    }

}
//if ($numcolor = "red" AND $assigned == '' AND $btn == '' AND $stat == '1') {
//  $numcolor = "";
//}
//print_r($match);
if ($stat == '4') { $color = "C2FACB"; }
elseif ($stat == '2') { $color="FCFBEA"; }
// else {
$ajaxedits .= "EditInPlace.makeEditable({ id: 'btn:$id' });\n";
$ajaxedits .= "EditInPlace.makeEditable({ id: 'assigned:$id' });\n";
$ajaxedits .= "EditInPlace.makeEditable({
    id: 'status:$id',
    type: 'select',
    save_url: 'optionedit_eip.php',
    options: {
        1: 'Free',
        2: 'In use',
        3: 'Disconnected',
        4: 'Ported Out'
    }
});";
//}
//<span class="red" id="status:$id">Dark Green</span>
//
if (isset($right[admin])) {
     $clear = "<a href=\"index.php?a=clearrow&id=$id\"> (Clear)</a>";
}   
eval("\$list_numbers .= \"".addslashes($TI[5])."\";");
}
$q->free;
```

the following

```
$match = meta_query($q->field('number'));
```

is the function where it calls to do the additional postgres checks which is listed above. Yes my code is ugly, im still a noob. :)

Comment: pg_free_result($result); this is not mysql

Comment: the main first query is MYSQL, the following two querys for the additional checks are postgres. Its a mess, I know. –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL queries within loops can be avoided. One way is to collect all $numbers in a php array and then run a single query after the loop.

`..WHERE baseinformation_directorynumber IN ($num1, $num2, ...);`

You'll get counts of all numbers in a single go. This will speed up the execution.

I've found a blog post containing more ways to avoid sql in loops. [check article](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2010/10/07/optimizing-sql-removing-queries-inside-loops/)

Comment: I part im confused about is, that im building a variable as it loops. On each loop, it checks the additions_checks(), then when it returns from that, there are a couple if/then's to colorize output for that 1 result. I dont understand how I'd still be able to do that after the query is run, but i Do understand how it would dramatically improve query times.

Comment: you can update the function `addition_checks($number);` to accept an array of numbers `addition_checks($numbers);` and then pass the numbers in sql query using `IN ( ..numbers here.. )`. Run a foreach on the output and collect numbers where count is = 0 then run the second query on those using the same `IN` syntax.

Comment: I can understand the part about colorizing output inside this function. Maybe you can also collect all outputs temporarily keyed by $number and then update those after loop.

Answer (score 2):

Look into using a `JOIN` on the two tables. Then you can compare the speeds, but depending on the number of rows that you have, a `JOIN` should be quicker than two queries.

Comment: This is your best bet. If you still aren't satisfied try creating a stored procedure.

Comment: if the two were on the same server, and DB type, this would be no problem. :)

Comment: There is no mention that you have these on different servers, and it doesn't seem to alter the queries you have above ... 
If the above code is exactly what you have in your PHP file, then it should be fine using JOINs.

Comment: I meant JOIN the first query & the one in the loop - that is the two in your PHP code, not the original query in bare SQL that you have.

Comment: Ok, i edited the title to be more specific, sorry about that. Even without the second query on the postgres side, its still very slow. Ill look into joining those though and see if it helps.